# Python: replace \n \r \t in a list excluding those starting \n\n and ends with \n\r\n\t

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-cleaning

My List:

> ['\n\r\n\tThis article is about sweet bananas. For the genus to which
>   banana plants belong, see Musa (genus).\n\r\n\tFor starchier bananas
>   used in cooking, see Cooking banana. For other uses, see Banana
>   (disambiguation)\n\r\n\tMusa species are native to tropical Indomalaya
>   and Australia, and are likely to have been first domesticated in Papua
>   New Guinea.\n\r\n\tThey are grown in 135
>   countries.\n\n\n\r\n\tWorldwide, there is no sharp distinction between
>   "bananas" and "plantains".\n\nDescription\n\r\n\tThe banana plant is
>   the largest herbaceous flowering plant.\n\r\n\tAll the above-ground
>   parts of a banana plant grow from a structure usually called a
>   "corm".\n\nEtymology\n\r\n\tThe word banana is thought to be of West
>   African origin, possibly from the Wolof word banaana, and passed into
>   English via Spanish or Portuguese.\n']

Example code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
re=requests.get('http://www.abcde.com/banana')
soup=BeautifulSoup(re.text.encode('utf-8'), "html.parser")
title_tag = soup.select_one('.page_article_title')
print(title_tag.text)
list=[]
for tag in soup.select('.page_article_content'):
    list.append(tag.text)
#list=([c.replace('\n', '') for c in list])
#list=([c.replace('\r', '') for c in list])
#list=([c.replace('\t', '') for c in list])
print(list)
```

After I scraping a web page, I need to do data cleansing. I want to replace all the `"\r"`, `"\n"`, `"\t"` as `""`, but I found that I have subtitle in this, if I do this, **subtitles and sentences are going to mix together**.

Every subtitle always starts with `\n\n` and ends with `\n\r\n\t`, is it possible that I can do something to distinguish them in this list like `\aEtymology\a`. It's not going to work if I replace `\n\n` and `\n\r\n\t` separately to `\a` first cause other parts might have the same elements like this `\n\n\r` and it will become like `\a\r`. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach

1. Replace the subtitles to a custom string, `<subtitles>` in the list
2. Replace the `\n`, `\r`, `\t` etc. in the list
3. Replace the custom string with the actual subtitle

Code

```
l=['\n\r\n\tThis article is about sweet bananas. For the genus to which banana plants belong, see Musa (genus).\n\r\n\tFor starchier bananas used in cooking, see Cooking banana. For other uses, see Banana (disambiguation)\n\r\n\tMusa species are native to tropical Indomalaya and Australia, and are likely to have been first domesticated in Papua New Guinea.\n\r\n\tThey are grown in 135 countries.\n\n\n\r\n\tWorldwide, there is no sharp distinction between "bananas" and "plantains".\n\nDescription\n\r\n\tThe banana plant is the largest herbaceous flowering plant.\n\r\n\tAll the above-ground parts of a banana plant grow from a structure usually called a "corm".\n\nEtymology\n\r\n\tThe word banana is thought to be of West African origin, possibly from the Wolof word banaana, and passed into English via Spanish or Portuguese.\n']

import re
regex=re.findall("\n\n.*.\n\r\n\t",l[0])
print(regex)

for x in regex:
    l = [r.replace(x,"<subtitles>") for r in l]

rep = ['\n','\t','\r']
for y in rep:
    l = [r.replace(y, '') for r in l]

for x in regex:
    l = [r.replace('<subtitles>', x, 1) for r in l]
print(l)
```

Output

```
['\n\nDescription\n\r\n\t', '\n\nEtymology\n\r\n\t']

['This article is about sweet bananas. For the genus to which banana plants belong, see Musa (genus).For starchier bananas used in cooking, see Cooking banana. For other uses, see Banana (disambiguation)Musa species are native to tropical Indomalaya and Australia, and are likely to have been first domesticated in Papua New Guinea.They are grown in 135 countries.Worldwide, there is no sharp distinction between "bananas" and "plantains".\n\nDescription\n\r\n\tThe banana plant is the largest herbaceous flowering plant.All the above-ground parts of a banana plant grow from a structure usually called a "corm".\n\nEtymology\n\r\n\tThe word banana is thought to be of West African origin, possibly from the Wolof word banaana, and passed into English via Spanish or Portuguese.']
```

Comment: This is very neat! And easy for me to learn and understand. Just a question list = [r.replace('<subtitles>', x, 1) for r in list], what does 1 use for? When I removed it, it printed out the same result. Just curious :) Thanks!

Comment: @Makiyo 1 is to replace the first occurrence of <subtitles> alone. If you remove 1 then the subtitles will be the same in the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re    

print([re.sub(r'[\n\r\t]', '', c) for c in list])
```

I think you may use regex

Comment: I don't think this is a correct answer,his "\n \r \t" mean '\n' or '\r' or '\t', if you read it as "\n\r\t",then the following sentence will be useless "starting \n\n and ends with \n\r\n\t .....". Check his example, there is no “\n\r\t” at all

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using regular expressions:

```
import re
subtitle = re.compile(r'\n\n(\w+)\n\r\n\t')
new_list = [subtitle.sub(r"\a\g<1>\a", l) for l in li]
```

`\g<1>` is a backreference to the (\w+) in the first regex. It lets you reuse what ever is in there.

Comment: Hi Jan! I tried it but it's not working, don't know if it's me put it in the wrong place. I just uploaded the entire code above :)

Comment: AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'compile'

Comment: That's because you are overwriting `re` in your code. `import re` and then `re = `
rename your request or use `import re as regex` and substitude re with regex

Comment: nothing happened (no error), I just put them after list.append(tag.text)

Comment: Can you update your post so I can see the code your using now? Btw `http://www.abcde.com/banana` gives me a `404`